# ColdFusion: get the name of a file before uploading

Tags: coldfusion, file-upload

How can I get the filename of a file before I call the

```
<cffile action = "upload">
```

? I can get the filename of the temp file, but not of the actual filename. In PHP land I can use the $_FILES superglobal to get what I want - but as far as I can tell no such thing exists in ColdFusion.

I can get the filename client-side but would really want to do this server side.

Thanks

Comment: How extraordinarily typical of ColdFusion not to have such basic functionality.

Answer (score 19):

Yes this is possible. You can use this function to grab the client file name before using the cffile tag:

```
<cffunction name="getClientFileName" returntype="string" output="false" hint="">
    <cfargument name="fieldName" required="true" type="string" hint="Name of the Form field" />

    <cfset var tmpPartsArray = Form.getPartsArray() />

    <cfif IsDefined("tmpPartsArray")>
        <cfloop array="#tmpPartsArray#" index="local.tmpPart">
            <cfif local.tmpPart.isFile() AND local.tmpPart.getName() EQ arguments.fieldName> <!---   --->
                <cfreturn local.tmpPart.getFileName() />
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>

    <cfreturn "" />
</cffunction>
```

More info here: http://www.stillnetstudios.com/get-filename-before-calling-cffile/

Comment: It works! Thank you. It seems crazy that it's this difficult to get such a basic thing out of the request, but that is the life of a CF developer.

Comment: Nifty function! Thanks. Confirmed to work in ColdFusion 10.

Answer (score 10):

I'm using Railo and found the original filenames with:

`GetPageContext().formScope().getUploadResource('your_file_input_form_name').getName();`

maybe this works on an adobe server as well? its quite handy if you want to rename your uploaded file somehow and don't want it to get moved through two temp dirs (see [Renaming Files As They Are Uploaded (how CFFILE actually works)](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2004/07/renaming_files.html))

Comment: Thanks, I needed this exactly. Works like a charm!

Comment: FYI this only works in Railo, not Adobe ColdFusion. See my answer for how to do this in Adobe ColdFusion.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know of a way to find out before calling cffile, but there may be a workaround.

When you call `<cffile action="upload">` you can specify a result using `result="variable"`.  So, call the upload with the destination as a temp file.  Your result variable is a struct which contains the member clientFile, which is the name of the file on the client's computer.

Now, you can use `<cffile action="move">` to do whatever it is you need to do with the original filename.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... We considered this solution as it seems to be the only way. I'll leave this question open though for further answers... But I don't think we can get much better then what you posted.

Comment: This gives problems when you make multiple **file upload** requests in succession

Comment: Just tried this and it works very well.  I'm so glad to get my hands on this structure.

Answer (score 2):

WOW, i found a great and easy solution! with a little javascript

In this way you get the temp filename for the cffile upload and the actual file.jpg name for the database

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function PassFileName()
{
document.getElementById("fileName").value=document.getElementById("fileUp").value;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
File: <input type="file" name="fileUp" id="fileUp" size="20" onchange="PassFileName()" /> <br />
Title: <input type="text" name="Title" id="Title"><br />
<input type="hidden" id="fileName" size="20" name="fileName" />
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the name attribute defined on the input control, the file name will be in the FORM scope. For example:

```
<cfif not structIsEmpty(form)>
    <cfdump var="#form#">
<cfelse>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="#cgi.SCRIPT_NAME#">
            <input type="file" name="fileIn" />
            <input type="Submit" name="formSubmit">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Whoops, I left off the enctype. Now to mod myself down.

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to have client-side code populate a hidden form field with the filename, which you would then have server-side.

Ben Doom's answer is generally how I would approach it, though.

Comment: Yeah, we considered this too. But you can't count on your users not wielding a fierce FireBug to make your life miserable. I suppose you can kick the request back and flag the user if you find that the clientside var lied (once you do the upload and get the real filename)... But I would like a more elegent solution. Thanks for the answer though :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how we do it.  Basically, there is a file field, and a string field.  JavaScript grabs the filename from the browser before the form is submitted.  Obviously, you need to verify that the filename on the other end is actually present (it'll be blank if the user has JavaScript disabled, for example) and you'll need to parse the string to handle platform differences (`/users/bob/file.jpg` versus `C:\Documents and Settings\bob\file.jpg`)

```
<script>
    function WriteClientFileName(){
        $('ClientFileName').value = $('ClientFile').value;
    }
</script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="WriteClientFileName();">

    <input type="File" name="ClientFile" id="ClientFile">
    <input type="hidden" name="ClientFileName" id="ClientFileName" value="">

    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Incidentally, this technique is cross-language.  It'll work equally well in RoR, PHP, JSP, etc.

**Edit:** If a user is "wielding a fierce FireBug" what's the issue?  Even if they don't have Firebug, they can still rename the file on their end and change the input.  Plus, you're validating your inputs, right?

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to know the file name for uploaded files before saving to the server in ColdFuson, Railo or OpenBD. I typically generate 'my' new filename using the createUUID() function in advance of saving the file.