# Coldfusion Form.getPartsArray function

Tags: coldfusion

These two links reference the ability, in ColdFusion, to get the name of an uploaded file using form.getPartsArray(). However I can not find ColdFusion documentation on it. I would like to use this but not if it has been deprecated or will be. Does anyone have more information on the origin and fate of this function?

[ColdFusion: get the name of a file before uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860964/coldfusion-get-the-name-of-a-file-before-uploading)

http://www.stillnetstudios.com/get-filename-before-calling-cffile/

Comment: For the first link, the 2nd answer looks better than the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ColdFusion: get the name of a file before uploading

Ignoring the main question for a moment, can you elaborate on *why* you want to use it? Reason for asking is the title of the first question might give you a mistaken impression about what that method actually does. Form.getPartsArray() **does not provide access to file information before the file is uploaded.** The file is already on the server at that point, so in later versions of CF (with additional functionality) it does not necessarily buy you much over just using `cffile action=upload`.

> Does anyone have more information on the origin and fate of this
> function?

However, to answer your other question - it is an *undocumented* feature last I checked. (It was more useful in earlier versions of CF, which lacked some of the newer features relating to form fields and uploads.)

Internally, most form data can be handled using standard request objects, ie [HttpServletRequest](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/getpagecontext.html). However, those do not support *multipart* requests, ie file uploads. So a special handler is needed. Macromedia/Adobe chose to use the [com.oreilly.servlet](http://www.servlets.com/cos/) library for their internal implementation. That is what you are accessing when using `FORM.getPartsArray()`.

The O'Reilly stuff has been bundled with CF since (*at least*) CF8, which is a good indicator. However, using any internal feature always comes with the risk the implementation will change and break your application. Also, if you move to another engine, the code may not be supported/compatible. So "You pays your money, you takes your choice".

*CF8 / Form Scope*

[image: CF8 FORM.getPartsArray()]

Comment: I using it to get the file name of an uploaded file in order to manipulate the name and store the file.

Comment: @dutchlab - See my updates. Any reason you cannot just use `cffile`?

Comment: I'm using cffile however I'm also storing the name of the file in a database along with creating a pdf of the file. Using cfset filename = form.fileupload gives a tmp name assigned by ColdFusion which is of no use. By using the getparts I can combine date values entered by the user with the name of the file to create a new file name. It makes it so easy but I will rework using the result of cffile to eliminate the possibility this function stops working.

Comment: @dutchlab - Not sure if it is applicable in your case, but in most of my apps the physical file name and "user friendly" file names are stored separately. When files are uploaded, the app generates a unique file name, scrubbed of any invalid characters. I then store the physical name, plus the original file name (or a more user friendly version) in separate columns. When files are downloaded with cfcontent, I use the "friendly" version for the display name.

Comment: thanks for your time and suggestions. I used cffile result.clientFileName and result.clientFileExt to get the starting point of the file I then scrub cleintFileName and add other user entered values to that value to create a unique name for the pdf file. I store this value in the database.

Comment: Gotcha. I just meant the "physical" file name, and the "display" file name (for downloads) do not have *have* to be the same :-) Keeping them separate offers a lot of flexibility. You can apply whatever naming convention you want for the physical files, and a show a different file name to users when a file is downloaded, but all depends on the app.