# How do you tell files apart in the output from getPartsArray?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2021

We have some Coldfusion pages that accept files, and we're using some code on the target page to process those files, starting with this:

```
<cfset tmpPartsArray    = caller.form.getPartsArray() />
<cfif IsDefined("tmpPartsArray")>
    <cfloop array="#tmpPartsArray#" index="tmpPart">
        <cfif tmpPart.isFile()>
            <cfset thisFileName = tmpPart.getFileName() />
            <cfset thisExt      = listLast(thisFileName, ".")>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfif>
```

This worked fine in our initial tests, but when testing on a page with multiple form file inputs it would always take the name and extension of the first one (since there's nothing in the above to make sure we've got the *right* file field; just that we have *a* file field).  I need some way to make sure the tmpPart that I'm looking at is the *right* file.

When I dump tmpPart, I don't see any function that allows me to get the name of the input that the file came from.  I can get the original file name, but that doesn't help me because there's no way for me to get the original file name out of the form scope in CF so I still can't tell which file is the right file.

The only way I can figure to find the right tmpPart is to do a cfFile upload and then take the filename from that to compare against getFileName(), but the whole point of using the PartsArray is to avoid doing a cfFile upload.  (avoiding cfFile upload is a requirement that I cannot change)

Is there any way, when looping through the partsArray, to determine which file field we're looking at?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coldfusion Form.getPartsArray function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42397221/coldfusion-form-getpartsarray-function)

Comment: @haxtbh Thanks, but I don't believe so.  Unless I'm missing it, that doesn't provide a way for me, when uploading multiple files, to figure out which index in getPartsArray correlates to which input field.  For example, If users upload a profile photo and an avatar, I don't see a way to determine which getPartsArray row is the profile photo and which is the avatar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized after getting a second set of eyes on this that I was missing the functions inherited from the parent class, and could use getName() to get the fieldName of the submitted file.

```
            <cfset tmpPartsArray    = caller.form.getPartsArray() />
            <cfif IsDefined("tmpPartsArray")>
                <cfloop array="#tmpPartsArray#" index="tmpPart">
                    <cfif tmpPart.isFile() and tmpPart.getName() is attributes.filefield>
                        <cfset thisFileName = tmpPart.getFileName() />
                        <cfset thisExt      = listLast(thisFileName, ".")>
                    </cfif>
                </cfloop>
            </cfif>
```